# Dynamically Remove and Add a User Control (.ascx)

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, web-controls

After a page loads a user control, is there a way to remove the user control and replace it with a different one, without doing a browser refresh?

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in an event before ViewState is finalized. Set up both in codebehind, use a placeholder in the page, and swap out the controls accordingly...look up the page lifecycle events - I think you need to do it in an event before Load executes because by then ViewState is established.